# Search crawl failing on a specific list (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search, pdf, crawl

At one of our clients we have a library that contains folders, which contain pdf documents.

There are many files (7000 +), I'm not sure if this is relevant. And the entire site uses SSL.

When crawling this list the search crawl throws the following error sporadically: 
The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service. ( Error from SharePoint site: *** There is an error in XML document (1, 65537).

Pdf documents in this list are not crawled at all.

I have tried all the usual things, from checking that the list is crawlable, to forcing the re-index of the list from list settings, to changing registry key entries to up the available memory to search.

There is another list in exactly the same area as this one, that happily gets crawled with no issues.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?